# Why Opentelemetry spans with same trace ids could have different transaction ids in the Elastic APM?

Tags: php, go, open-telemetry, elastic-apm

I see a strange behavior for Opentelemetry integration. We have applications in PHP and Go which are linked with GRPC. I've made a [manual Opentelemetry integration](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/php/instrumentation/) for PHP (with [GRPC transport](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/php/exporters/#otlp)). However there is a strange situation when some of spans are not linked (but I'm absolutely sure that they should) despite the same trace id. Metadata tab for them shows different transaction ids but the same trace id. What could be a reason for such a behavior? I am able to find all of them by trace id on APM's Traces tab. Also, in some endpoints (also PHP http -> PHP GRPC Client -> Go) everything is correct: I see the same transaction id, same trace id and all the spans for the operation on one screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the [data model documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/current/data-model-transactions.html) details, transactions are just a special type of span, so this is expected.  I would expect to see both transactions in the waterfall when viewing the full trace for the trace you're inspecting here.

Comment: I can not attach full screenshots of a proper transactions and case with different transactions with same trace id because of some sensitive data. I believe that in case of Opentelemetry different spans must be merged in the same transaction because they have same trace id and it's is the final source of true (in case of Opentelemetry only). From the other POV in our services I saw other endpoints in the same schema (PHP-otel -> grpc -> Go) where everything was fine: different spans with same trace id from PHP and Go were in one transaction.